# ITextSharp XMLWorker not showing images

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, itext, xmlworker

I am developing MVC application, and i have problem with XMLWorker and ImageProvider. My images are not shown in pdf afrer rendering html that it receives.

Here is the code:

```
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        string cssPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content");

        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            using (Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50))
            {
                using (PdfWriter pdfWrt = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output))
                {
                    pdfWrt.CloseStream = false;
                    pdfWrt.PageEvent = new PdfWriterEvents("watermark");
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    HtmlPipelineContext context = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                    context.SetTagFactory(iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
                    context.SetImageProvider(new MyImageProvider());
                    var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
                    cssResolver.AddCssFile(cssPath + "\\main.css", true);
                    IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(context, new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDoc, pdfWrt)));
                    var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
                    var parser = new XMLParser();
                    parser.AddListener(worker);


                    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(html))
                    {
                        parser.Parse(sr);
                    }
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    byte[] test = output.GetBuffer();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/PDFs/test.pdf"), test);

                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my ImageProvider implementation:

```
public class MyImageProvider : AbstractImageProvider
{
    public override string GetImageRootPath()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images");
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: To help you debug, instead of parsing directly to the `Document` object try writing to a custom `IElementHandler` so you can walk each object. See [the second and third code blocks here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24498296/231316) for how to do that. Also, instead of `output.GetBuffer();` always use `output.ToArray();`. The former actually includes uninitialized (junk) bytes that will corrupt your PDF in certain common scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried with custom IElementHandler, it did`t work. Anyway, i will probably remove images from HTML and create them as pdf images

Comment: I suggested the `IElementHandler` only so you could put a breakpoint on your `for` loop and see what iTextSharp is actually doing.

Comment: I tried again with custom IElementHandler and it seems that the img tag is not recognized as instance of IWritable interface. When i put div or span as my html it works, and add method is executed. For img tags it is not the case, add method is not firing. Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem was in image url. ImageProvider was not returning correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the image source tags to include the entire url to get them to work.